# what the advantage or disadvantages if i used youtube-API or present the video in a webview

Tags: android, android-layout, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

In YouTube Player API  when I press fullscreen it repeats the video from the beginning ,any help to solve this problem

Also when I lock my phone (sleep mode) it stop playing , I want it to resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you add fullscreen, orientation flags to your AndroidManifest it won't. Basically by default, it recreates the activity, hence restarts.

  ```
  <activity
      android:name="MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
  ```
- YouTube prohibits running videos in sleep mode, or in background. It's clear in [YouTube TOS](http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms). Hence there won't be any APIs and doing workarounds will be against the TOS.