# How to add a music player to my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, youtube-api

So I made a website someday, and now via webview and the YouTube Api I made it possible to listen to the music on my phone.

But... as soon as I close my app it stops playing the music.
How can I possibly add a music player and make it so the music keeps playing after the phone goes on standby mode?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what the advantage or disadvantages if i used youtube-API or present the video in a webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075849/what-the-advantage-or-disadvantages-if-i-used-youtube-api-or-present-the-video-i)

Answer (score 1):

Even thought I haven't deal with Youtube API for Android, I think that what you are trying to do is impossible. Even the Youtube App doesn't keep music playing after the phone goes on standby mode. That's their policy about music videos on Youtube.

Comment: Hmm, there are some apps that do have that feature and use YouTube videos on the play store... How is that?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Read Ibrahim's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075849/what-the-advantage-or-disadvantages-if-i-used-youtube-api-or-present-the-video-i

Comment: Ibrahim's answer: "YouTube prohibits running videos in sleep mode, or in background. It's clear in YouTube TOS. Hence there won't be any APIs and doing workarounds will be against the TOS."