# How to keep music playing in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube-api, android-webview

So I made a music streaming website streaming from YouTube the other day.
Now with WebView and the YouTube app I made the app 'native'.
Is there anyway to make the app not stop when you put your phone on standby , and maybe add music controller?

Comment: Is it really necessary to post the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914587/how-to-add-a-music-player-to-my-app

Comment: Ow shoot, I thought the otherone didn't come through