# Android App with Youtube API. Run the music while app is minimized or the phone in hold mode

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api, minimize

I'm a noob in programming Android apps but I did my best and now I made an Android app with my own YouTube API. I am a little bit proud that I can run the app and listen to music. As you may know, if you listen to music with the YouTube app, the music stops when you minimize the App or you change into hold mode. I want my app to still play the music when I minimize it or put it in hold mode (disable the screen). As I am a beginner, I don't know how to do that. I looked at a lot of forums to get some clues but maybe somebody here can get me on a good track.

Any help are welcome and will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1):

As per Ibrahim's response in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075849/what-the-advantage-or-disadvantages-if-i-used-youtube-api-or-present-the-video-i):

> YouTube prohibits running videos in sleep mode, or in background.

However, I would still suggest that you please go through [YouTube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) since YouTube may, in its sole discretion, modify or revise these Terms of Service and policies at any time.